# Difference between using a prototype and a plugin in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I need to use a simple tracking service in my vue js project...

In my app.js I can use this in two ways...

For example:-

1) To create a prototype:

```
import moment from 'moment';
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$moment', { value: moment });
```

2) Using the plugin to incorporate the service inside it:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  install: function(Vue,) {
    Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$http', { value: axios });
  }
}
```

Both are using prototypes and both ways are working for me... I just need to know the difference between those two methods...

Comment: There is no difference!

Comment: In that case what is the advantage of having them both?

Comment: I think when you use/create a plugin, it's easier for import and use it in another project!

Comment: Is there anything like `Object.definePrototype` in JS?  Or is this mistake and it should be `Object.defineProperty` ? I haven't seen it before.

Comment: Sorry you are right!! the edit has been done... @Randall Flagg but my question stays the same.

Answer (score 3):

Plugin should have a `install` property like you used:

```
const MyPlugin = {
    install: function(Vue,) {
        Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$http', { value: axios });
    }
}
```

when you usse a plugin you should call the `Vue.use()` method

```
Vue.use(MyPlugin);
```

this.just calls the `install` method on the plugin

in  your case you are just setting a prototype on the `Vue`.

Plugins are mostly used for developing 3rd party libraries or assets to be incorporated into othe vuejs projects.

For example consider you developed a vue component which can  be used by others;

You define a plugin as such:

```
import MyComponent from './path'

const MyPlugin = {
    install: function(Vue,) {
        Vue.component('my-component', MyComponent);
    }
}

export MyPlugin;
```

Now when you publish your plugin on `npm` ,others can use your component as follows:

```
import MyComponent from 'MyComponent'


Vue.use(MyComponent);
```

Now `my-component` is available globally in any other components and can be used as:

```
<my-component></my-component>my-component>
```

Comment: I understand what you say... But is there a difference between them or not? Coz I quite didn't get the answer for my question.

Comment: @JegadeshBS in your case not since you are doing the same i.e adding a prototype on `Vue` in both cases